# How can i calculate the speed of a fan in a commercial jet engine?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, drag, speed

How can i calculate the speed of a fan in a commercial jet engine if i already know the ρ(Air density), Cp (Maximum output), A (Rotor swept area), V(wind speed) and Drag coefficient? and what other data would i need in order to calculate the speed?

Comment: -1.What research have you done to try to find an answer?

Comment: Are you asking about the speed of the fan when the engine is not running, but there is some wind blowing through it? Otherwise, the speed depends mainly on the power that the engine is producing!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Euler *turbine equation*, the angular velocity of a blade row is given by,

$$ \omega = c_p \frac{T_{T,i} - T_{T,e}}{r_i v_i - r_e v_e} $$

where $T_T$ is the total temperature, $c_p$ is the specific heat at constant pressure of the fluid, $v$ is the tangential velocity of the fluid, $r$ is the radius, and the subscripts $i$ and $e$ correspond to the inlet and exit of the blade row. However, other expressions exist that are directly related to the power output of the turbo-machinery,

$$ \omega = \frac{\dot{W}}{\tau} $$

where $\dot{W}$ is the power output of the turbo-machinery and $\tau$ is the corresponding output torque.